Why is CORS not working in NestJS APP + NGINX?
Why do I get cors error and invalid headers when requesting from frontend http://localhost:3000?
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService<AllConfigType>);

  app.enableShutdownHooks();
  app.setGlobalPrefix(
    configService.getOrThrow('app.apiPrefix', { infer: true }),
    {
      exclude: ['/'],
    },
  );
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
  });
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(validationOptions));
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    // ResolvePromisesInterceptor is used to resolve promises in responses because class-transformer can't do it
    // https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/549
    new ResolvePromisesInterceptor(),
    new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)),
  );

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setDescription('API docs')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);

  await app.listen(configService.getOrThrow('app.port', { infer: true }));
}
void bootstrap();

Nignx
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; # Порт на котором запускается ваше No>
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:3000;


    }

Postman result header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: tru

Sometimes I get response headers: 0.
I've been agonizing for 5 hours and I don't know how to fix it.

Your application should not handle CORS at all. CORS is an infrastructure matter, something that is under the sole authority of the people that manage the infrastructure that will host the application: they are the one who decide how CORS is applied, either at their web server or the reverse proxy level.

You are requesting the page at http://localhost:3000 but your nginx config is changing it to http://localhost:4000 via proxy_pass. Have you tried
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4000',
    credentials: true,
  });

to match your nginx config?

I found the problem. This is very stupid -
I changed the line
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });

on
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

It rewrote the Origin header
